# why the getx debounce did not execute in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I want to using debounce in [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) controller, but finnaly I found that the debounce code block did not executed. This is my `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_state.dart';

import 'main_controller.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<MainController>(
        init: MainController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          void _onItemTapped(int index) {
            controller.updateIndex(index);
          }

          return Scaffold(
              body: Text("ddddd"),
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                  items: [
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: GestureDetector(onDoubleTap: () {}, child: Icon(Icons.home)), label: "a"),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: GestureDetector(onDoubleTap: () {}, child: Icon(Icons.subscriptions)), label: "b"),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.rss_feed), label: "c"),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.school), label: "d"),
                  ],
                  currentIndex: controller.selectIndex.value,
                  fixedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  onTap: _onItemTapped,
                  unselectedItemColor: Color(0xff666666),
                  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed));
        });
  }
}
```

and this is the `main_controller.dart`:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_controllers.dart';

class MainController extends GetxController {
  var selectIndex = 0.obs;
  final _count = 0.obs;

  void updateIndex(int index) {
    selectIndex.value = index;

    debounce(
      _count,
      (value) {
        print("debounce -> " + value.toString());
      },
      time: Duration(seconds: 2),
    );

    update();
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the workers methods in `Getx` should only be used in the `onInit()`, or the `initState()` as the `Getx` [author say in this issue](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/549#issuecomment-685162400) :

> Workers must be on onInit, constructor of Controller, or initState.
> It doesn't matter if the data will arrive later, the moment it is declared, they will observe that variable until it is available.
> Quickly looking at your reproduction code, the updateUser function is called whenever a key is pressed.
> In this way, a new Worker is created.

so using debounce inside a specific method will result in only in errors an unexpected behaviors.

you can do this :

```
@override
void onInit() {
  debounce(
      _count,
      (value) {
        print("debounce -> " + value.toString());
      },
      time: Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
  super.onInit();
   }
```